# Simple Calculation in R Shiny App gives another output than the same calculation in Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny

In my Shiny App i have three inputs. A `selectInput()` where a user wants to select an article; A `textInput()` where a user wants to specify a stock; an `actionButton()` which triggers a `tableOutput()`. This `tableOutput()` gives the user a dataframe with the first entry in the dataframe that matches the filter.

For example: a user wants to know in which week does the article he chooses in `selectInput()` a stock which he chooses in `textInput()`. So he selects the article `34343` and wants to know, when does the article `34343` have an avilable stock of 100. The output would give him the answere which is in week 1, since there is available stock of 210.57.

The problem i face here is, when i specify a stock that is greater than 210,57, for example 211, the expected week would be week 3, but the output says its week 2 with an stock of 94.42, which basically means that 94.42 is greater than 210.57.

How can this be?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(id=as.integer(c(34343, 34343, 34343)), week=as.integer(c(1,2,3)), stock=as.double(c(210.57,94.42,412.31)))

ui <- fluidPage(

    selectInput(inputId = "id", "Select", choices = df$id, multiple = F, selectize = T),
    textInput(inputId = "stock", "Stock", placeholder = "i.e. 100"),
    actionButton(inputId = "click", "Click"),
    tableOutput(outputId = "table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    result = eventReactive(input$click, {
        df %>% filter(id %in% input$id) %>% 
            distinct(id, week, stock) %>%
            group_by(id) %>%
            slice(first(which(stock >= input$stock)))
    })
    
    output$table = renderTable({
        result()
    })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `slice()` statement needs to be:

```
slice(first(which(stock >= as.numeric(input$stock))))
```

because `input$stock` is a string that is not automatically converted to a number.   Consider how these two different filter statements work:

```
> filter(df, stock >= "212")
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#      id  week stock
#   <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1 34343     2  94.4
# 2 34343     3 412. 
> filter(df, stock >= 212)
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#        id  week stock
#     <int> <int> <dbl>
# 1 34343     3  412.
```

The code below produces the expected output.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(id=as.integer(c(34343, 34343, 34343)), week=as.integer(c(1,2,3)), stock=as.double(c(210.57,94.42,412.31)))

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(inputId = "id", "Select", choices = df$id, multiple = F, selectize = T),
  textInput(inputId = "stock", "Stock", placeholder = "i.e. 100"),
  actionButton(inputId = "click", "Click"),
  tableOutput(outputId = "table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  result = eventReactive(input$click, {
    df %>% filter(id %in% input$id) %>% 
      distinct(id, week, stock) %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      slice(first(which(stock >= as.numeric(input$stock))))
  })
  
  output$table = renderTable({
    result()
  })
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```